# Reclaiming memory from GridView Bitmaps that are off-screen and are not likely to be used

Tags: android, android-gridview

I have a GridView that I use to display images from an API.
The normal user behavior is to go to the bottom and pull more results.
I plan to scale the bitmaps down, but there will be many of them.
Therefore, I think it might be safe to delete images that are many pages above the current page.

Are the old images deleted by the GridView at some point?
The normal usage is to use the view cache, which looks like the GridView is holding on to them.